# Undefined method for rather straightforward models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application that creates microposts under categories and subcategories (which I call selections). The user can write in two fields, the category field and the selection field. My models are:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_content, :selection_content, :category_id, :selection_id, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :selection

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :category_content, presence: true
  validates :selection_content, presence: true


  default_scope order: 'microposts.created_at DESC'

end


class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :id, :count, :c_count
  has_many :selections
  has_many :comments

  default_scope order: 'categories.count DESC'

end


class Selection < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :count, :category_id
  belongs_to :category

  default_scope order: 'selections.count DESC'

end
```

In my console, when I create a user u and enter "u.microposts" I get the desired response (a list of microposts created by u). When I create a category c and enter "c.selections" I also get the desired response (a list of selections that belong to c). But when I enter "s.microposts" I get the following error message- "undefined method `microposts' for #<Selection:0x57c6b40>". Similarly, when I enter "u.microposts" I get the error message- "undefined method`microposts' for #".  Any ideas why this is happening?

I am developing on Windows using RubyMine. I am definitely moving to OS X soon, because I have to make too many hoops working around the Windows environment, but I don't see why this would make a difference here.

Comment: Add `has_many :microposts` in your `Selection` class.  But I think you could simplify these three using `has_many ... through` relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"s.microposts"

This will look for a `has_many` relation in the 's' class (a `Selection` object) named `microposts` but you haven't defined one.

Add the following to the `Selection` class:

```
has_many :microposts
```

Comment: Of course. I must be getting dyslexic, working the late shift. Thank you for knocking sense into my head. Yes, I made the change, restarted the console, and everything works as it should.